# nodejs JSON.parse() of stack overflow API

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, stackexchange-api

Here is my code.

```
var request = require('request');
var API = "https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/users?page=1&order=desc&sort=reputation&site=stackoverflow";

request(API, function(e//console.dir(body);
if( err || response.statusCode != 200 ) {
    console.log("Error",err); return;
}

var stringify = JSON.stringify(body);
var obj = JSON.parse(stringify);

var items = obj.items;
for (var i in items) {
   var item = items[i];
   var display_name = item.display_name;
   console.log("display_name", display_name);
}

});
```

node stack.js

I would like to get display_name from json(https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/users?page=1&order=desc&sort=reputation&site=stackoverflow). 
However, nothing happens(var items gets "undefined"). 
What should I do to fix it?

Comment: Try removing the JSON.stringify

Comment: Thank you for answering my question. However, I already tried  what you said then got an error. In addition, I searched the similar case I got and I add JSON.stringify. Unfortunately, it hasn't worked well. Anyway, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You're using a `for in` loop when you should just be using a regular `for` loop. `for in` is for iterating over the properties of an object - where you want to iterate over the elements of an array:

```
for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
    var item = items[i];
    var display_name = item.display_name;
    console.log("display_name", display_name);
}
```

Comment: tymeJV, thank you for answering, but in my case, items has a problem because items is returned "undefined". Anyway, thanks.

Comment: I solved this problem. The problem was that Stack Overflow compressed JSON file.